# Undefined reference 'gluOrtho2d' error in opengl using with c

Tags: c, gcc, linker, glu

> Undefined reference 'gluOrtho2d' error in opengl using with c

The above error comes when the following code is executed in C.

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Set clear color to white

    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500);

    // Draw sky
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Light blue color
    glVertex2f(200.0, 80.0);
    glVertex2f(100.0, 200.0);
    glVertex2f(200.0, 200.0);
    glVertex2f(200.0, 80.0);
    glEnd();

    
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Assignment");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to draw the below scene without using the default coordinate system in openGL and trying to make the (0,0) at the bottom left.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtXZ3.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)